# Get count of member's messages in channel in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Is there any way how to count messages of specified user in specified Discord channel in discord.js? When I use:

```
const countMyMessages = async (channel, member) => {
    const messages = await channel.messages.fetch()
    const myMessages = message.filter(m => m.author.id === member.id)
    console.log(myMessages.size)
}
```

Only 50 messages are fetched, so I can't count all messages of user. And option `limit` can have max value 100. `/guilds/guild_id/messages/search` API on the other hand is not available for bots.

Comment: The only way to do this I think is to fetch *all* the messages (in batches of 100). I recommend storing the message count of each user in a database and either incrementing this counter on every message or update it with only the new messages when required. If this is a viable solution let me know and I'll write up a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a storage system to keep this kind of statistics on Discord.

I recommend you to use SQLite at first (like [Enmap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enmap) npm package).

I can quickly draw a structure for you based on [this one](https://enmap.evie.dev/examples/points).

```js
const Enmap = require("enmap");
client.messages = new Enmap("messages");

client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.guild) {
    const key = `${message.guild.id}-${message.author.id}`;
    client.messages.ensure(key, {
      user: message.author.id,
      guild: message.guild.id,
      messages: 0
    });
    client.messages.inc(key, "messages");


    // Do your stuff here.
    console.log(client.messages.get(key, "messages"))
  }
});
```