# How to get the total count of sent messsages in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to create a bot slash command that responds with the number of messages a user has sent.

This is the current code of the slash command, I am not sure the discord class, properties, or method to use in this regard, please I need some help.

Here is the current state of the code

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("user")
        .setDescription("Replies with number of messages a user ha sent"),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply(`${}`);
    },
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get count of member's messages in channel in discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68740334/get-count-of-members-messages-in-channel-in-discord-js)

Comment: I tried the suggestion but i get an error message...

Comment: @Julia It worked for me, I had to make some modifications, thank you